# InternalResourceViewResolver in SpringMVC

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

Today I happened a question about spring mvc `InternalResourceViewResolver`. To be honest, here is the project structure:
[image]

this's the snippet of my code:
[image: InternalResourceResolver has something wrong]

maybe stack has some trouble on list block code and I put the screen snapshot here.the first time I wrote`viewResolver.setPrefix("/")`. Then I write a simple controller having a method index whose mapping is index and return charsequence "index", In my opinion typing `http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/index` should return an index.jsp page, actually a 404 page, so I think there must be something wrong on the previous code about the `internalResourceViewResolver`.
I have realized it on STS where that code was written like this one: `viewResover.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/classes/views/")` and I know this folder is under the projectName folder and whose contents are those runtime jsp output file, but when I changed to IntelliJ Idea this IDE. I find there is one "out" folder who act the role of output folder for the project,and you can also see from the first image.
After saying so much intermediate process, is there anybody who can tell me what I should write as the parameter of `setPrefix` method.thank you so much.
Update:
I deployed my application context as "hello", but this seems not work for my question.
Ok,this's the controller.

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String hello(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just don't set the prefix :)

Comment: no,it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK!this question made me update these days.i got it finally by myself.
`viewResolver.setPrefix("/");` is right.but why i set it and start tomcat got a 404 error because there are something i misunderstood and follow these step made this question resolved:
1) go to project structure(command + ;)
2) "Artifacts"-->"+"-->"Web Application:Exploded"-->change the artifact name you like.and here is the screenshot:
[image: my artifact]
3) "Facets"-->"+"-->"web"-->"projectModule"-->"fix"(right bottom of this page)-->"include artifacts"-->"ok"
4) "edit configuration"-->"Deployment"-->"+"-->"include artifact"-->"ok"
after the third step i have seen the output root folder has changed.and there are two item "WEB-INF" and blablabla.ok,this question should have come to an end.
the fourth step make some configuration on tomcat and restart tomcat and type url,ok!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your project structure, `viewResolver.setPrefix("/")` is correct. Can you share details of your controller where you have mapped the URL please? A function mapped to the URL "/index" should return ModelAndView with name "index".

Instead, if you just want the index.jsp page to load as home, add this snippet to your web.xml file:

`<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>`

Now, http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/ should open your index.jsp view.

Comment: it's not the issue of index.jsp and i have already put the really simple controller there,i have no idea if viewResolver.setprefix("/") is correct.